# how to get the value from arraylist

Tags: android, arrays

I am Working on XML parsing  coming from server the xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Activities><Activity ID="1" Title="Title1" />
</Activities
```

i have parse the XML and now i have my ID and Title in my ArrayList , Now I only Want to get the Title value so that i can fill my spinner(DropDown)

For getting value in arraylist i am using beans (set get beans) after getting how can i individually get the value if title

so that i can fill my Spinner with title value

Please do help 
Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code of parsing and storing in Arraylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an ArrayAdapter, as below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list)
{
  public Object getItem(int position)
  {
      BeanClass map=list.get(position);//I assume bean class Have name BeanClass
      return map.getTitle();
  }
};
```

and set this adapter to spinner.